# When transmembrane proteins destined for the plasma membrane are in the ER membrane are they in their final folded form?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, cell-membrane, intracellular-transport

I am studying how transmembrane proteins are made and I have read that proteins that are destined for the plasma membrane are initially in the ER membrane and do not get translocated into the ER lumen unlike other proteins.

I was wondering when a transmembrane protein destined for the cell membrane is in the ER membrane, is in its native form (e.g. final, folded form?). I am asking this because I read that the ribosomes are on the ER membrane, and that protein translocation through the ER membrane occurs co-translationally, meaning that it's occurring as the mRNA is being translated. Would the protein get folded as it's moving through the ER membrane?

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: This topic isn't fully understood, but proteins seem to be considered to become folded within the ER membrane, and the transmembrane integration system is compared to chaperone functionality. I found a nice review-paper to this topic. Check its sources for further reading to specific interests. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2814870/

Comment: The speed of folding/refolding is much faster than translation speed. So I expect much folding to happen during translation. Of course, proteins that become exposed to the different extracellular environment may refold then.